# How to delete an image from the cache broswer after shown on php?

Tags: php, ajax, browser, browser-cache

How to delete an image from the broswer cache  after shown on php? I would like to delete this image from cache browsers, after displaying this image on browsers.

Loading of images should be increased gradually, as the bypass list with the heading, images should not be accumulated in the memory browser, ie after displaying deleted. Display each subsequent offer must only after the next image is loaded into the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can't clear the browser cache in PHP.

But, if you append a random ID on the end of the image, the browser will treat it as a new image.

e.g images/image.jpg?2124124

example:

```
$cacheId = Math.floor(Math.random()*50000);
echo 'image/image.jpg?' . $cacheId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete the cache from your code. But, you can change the filename or append a query string so that the browser does a fresh request for the resource (Versioning). You can  also try setting 'CACHE-CONTROL' in the header

Answer (score -1):

Each browser have a plugin to clear the cache. In FF I was using this: https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/clear-cache-button/

In other you have to search..

Comment: I like do this on php in programming